# I want to install wxpython_phoenix on raspberrypi3

Tags: raspberry-pi, wxpython

I am trying to run the gui program on raspberrypi3 using `python3.6.1` and the `wx module`

I'm looking for `wxpython_phoenix` for the raspbian operating system, but not at https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/linux/. Do you mind installing debian8?

I am trying to install this by referring to the manual. `sudo pip3 install --upgrade --pre -f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshotbuilds/linux/gtk3/debian-8/wxPython-4.0.0a3.dev3059+4a5c5d9-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl`

But is not it because it is different from the Linux operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wxPython 4 is out now, which is based on Phoenix. You can just install it like this:

```
pip install wxPython
```

Note that you may need to install webkit BEFORE you install wxPython as I have had mine fail when webkit isn't there. The creators of wxPython are working on an update that will ignore this sort of thing soon.

Comment: Hi @Mike Driscoll,  could you please share the libs you installed (commands) I tried but does not work  wxPython installation yet... many thanks

Comment: I haven't installed wxPython on Rasbian before so I don't know what the libs to install are called there. But the error message I received on my Xubuntu box was that I didn't have webkit, so I Googled how to install that and got it working. I know one of my coworkers had to install a few other libs, but it was always obvious from the logs what lib to install.